# What is комфорт and why is it cheaper than not комфорт?

Tags: trains, russia

Looking at trains in Russia, I've found that for the same class, комфорт is cheaper than a ticket not marked as комфорт:

[image: комфорт]

In the image above, for the train № 042В «Москва – Воркута», the prices are:

- 2-cl. sleeping compt., from 6.194 ₽
- 2-cl. sleeping compt. (комфорт), from 5.793 ₽
- 3-cl. open sleeping, from 4.232 ₽
- 3-cl. open sleeping (комфорт), from 4,060 ₽

In both 2nd and 3rd class, the option with комфорт is the cheaper alternative.  But from the word, I would expect it to be more comfortable.  I thought it might just be a quirk due to some travel classes being sold out, just like how one sometimes find 1st class cheaper than 2nd class on the Thalys, but I checked several other dates on this route, and on those dates комфорт is also cheaper.  What is the difference and why is комфорт cheaper?

Comment: Could be a wonky translation on that website. I checked a few other websites and saw only differences in price acc. to travel classes (e.g. 3Д, the description of the amenities was always provided), with the "comfort" ones always more expensive than the standard ones.

Comment: Here's the list of classes for your carrier (FPK) if it helps: http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/en?STRUCTURE_ID=5328&layer_id=3290&refererLayerId=3290&id=2511

Comment: Comparing the prices on the Russian and English pages, it seems like a pricing glitch exclusive in the English version. I'm really curious if one can actually take advantage of it if they feel adventurous enough!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there is a bit strange issue that "non-comfort" class is more comfortable than "comfort" (the screenshot from Russian ticket site [rasp.yandex.ru](https://rasp.yandex.ru) at the bottom). It says that in **2Т** class there are meal, toilet with shower, TV set included and it costs 7.269 RUB for upper place. While in **2Л** class there isn't any meal included, so it costs for 445 RUB less.

[image: 2nd classes (in Russian)]

Comment: In English: http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/en?STRUCTURE_ID=5328

Answer (score 1):

It could possibly be:

- A wonky translation
- More комфорт tickets are available so maybe they dropped the price

I can confirm that комфорт means comfort